# MySql Query with INNER JOIN, GROUP BY and Max

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have two tables, one that looks like this:

```
ID, Datetime, User_ID, Location and Status // the rest is not relevant
```

And the other looks like this:

```
 ID, Lastname // the rest is not relevant
```

Now I only want to get the entry of the first table with the highest `Datetime` per `User_ID` and ask the other table the `lastname` of the `User_ID`. Simple...

I tried it this way (whick looks like the most promising but is false nontheless):

```
SELECT w.Datetime, w.User_ID, w.Status, e.Lastname
FROM worktimes AS w
INNER JOIN employees AS e 
ON w.User_ID=e.ID 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT max(Datetime) AS Datetime, User_ID
  FROM worktimes 
  WHERE Datetime>1467583200 AND Location='16' 
  GROUP BY User_ID
  ORDER BY Datetime DESC
) AS v
ON v.User_ID=w.User_ID
GROUP BY w.User_ID 
ORDER BY e.Nachname;
```

Could someone give me a hint please? I'm really stuck at this for a while now and now i begin to get some knots in my brain... :(

Comment: how about if you create a little sqlfiddle with some data. Show a tabular what you Expect. And someone bangs it out.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch from right join to left join! (People usually have enough problems with left join, and right join is way more confusing... It's easier to think main table left join optional data, than optional data right join main table.)

Comment: see, these other guys are much smarter, more literate.

Comment: The left join would not work here, because i would have to switch the tables... the left table is much bigger than the right one, so i would get thousands of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, actually:

```
SELECT w.Datetime, w.User_ID, w.Status, e.Lastname
FROM worktimes w INNER JOIN
     employees e 
     ON w.User_ID = e.ID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT max(Datetime) AS Datetime, User_ID
      FROM worktimes 
      WHERE Datetime > 1467583200 AND Location = '16' 
      GROUP BY User_ID
     ) ww
     ON ww.User_ID = w.User_ID AND w.DateTime = ww.DateTime
ORDER BY e.Nachname;
```

Notes:

- You do need to join on the `DateTime` value.
- The `RIGHT JOIN` is unnecessary.  I replaced it with a `LEFT JOIN`, but I'm not sure that is what you want either.  You might start with an `INNER JOIN` to see if that produces what you want.
- Do not use `ORDER BY` in subqueries in most circumstances.
- You do not need the `GROUP BY` in the outer query

Comment: I need a RIGHT JOIN because the table to the left is too big to use a left join. But with a RIGHT JOIN it seems to work fine... i will test some more, but thanks so far. You're a great help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is known as [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). In standard SQL it can be implemented using `APPLY` and `LATERAL` constructs. Unfortunatelly, not all RDBMS support these elegant solutions. For example, [MSSQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx), recent versions of [Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) and [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html) have these constructs, but **MySQL** does not. IMHO, it is a real pain for MySQL users, because in recent years MySQL started to lean towards standard, but in some strange manner - by default it switches off its non-standard hacks, but does not implement standard counterparts. For example, your own query presented in your question will not work by default in recent versions of MySQL, because sorting in subqueries is not supported any more and to make it work you have to use some nasty hack - add `LIMIT some_really_big_number` to the subquery.

Comment: BTW, the reason why sorting may not work in subqueries is because in theory sorted table is not a "set", but is a "cursor". I hope some wise experts will correct me, if I am mistaken.